# Office 365 Powershell - Get LastPasswordChangeStamp for members of a security group

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I'm hoping that someone will be able to offer some guidance. I'm trying to build a Powershell Script that enables me to get the LastPasswordChangeStamp for members of specific security group. The group I'm testing with has 10 members but when I run the script, it behaves as follows:

- Runs successfully with no errors
- Returns 80 results (8 x 10 members)

Code below:

```
#Define the Security Group
$securityGroup = Get-MsolGroup -GroupType “Security” | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq “GroupName”}

# Get Members
$securityGroupMembers = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $securityGroup.ObjectId

# Iterate each user
ForEach($Member in $securityGroupMembers){

    #Get underlying msol user
    #$user = Get-MsolUser -ObjectId -$mUser.ObjectId

    #Determine password age
    Get-MsolUser | select DisplayName, LastPasswordChangeTimeStamp

}
```

I cant see why its looping multiple times and was hoping someone could offer some guidance on where I'm going wrong.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You forgot ObjectId for Get-MsolUser so it probably tries to display all users. Remember to use $member.objectid in there

Comment: Can you show us the values of `$SecurityGroupMembers` and `$SecurityGroup`? One suggestion I have is that you are using smart curly quotes instead of dumb straight quotes. Most languages don't recognize smart quotes as grouping delimiter so try replacing `-GroupType “Security”` with `-GroupType "Security"`

Comment: one thing that will _sometimes_ give you problems is the typographic quotes in your posted code. those curved/curly/slanted quotes will occasionally be misread as something "else". it's good self defence to replace them with straight quotes so that PoSh does not get confused. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is in your foreach Loop. you're saying For each member in the group, Get all users in your entire tenant, and display their displayname and lastpasswordchangetimestamp.

you can replace that entire foreach loop with

```
$securityGroupMembers | get-msoluser  | select DisplayName, LastPasswordChangeTimeStamp
```

just delete the entire foreach loop.

Comment: That makes complete sense @alphaz18. I've made the suggested changes to my script and it worked a treat. Thanks for your help